# How to Use Arrow Keys to Navigate a Vertical Page

Tags: html, scroll, keyboard

I have a webpage with photos on it. I would like the viewer to be able to use the arrow keys (up, down, left, right) to advance. Typically the down key scrolls about 10 pixels. I'd like the down key and the right key to advance to the next photo, or say, 1000 pixels. I'd like the up and the left key to do the same, but in reverse, so scroll back up the page those same 1000 pixels. I thought to assign each set of photos an anchor (#) tag, and have the page scroll to the next tag. I hardly know HTML, CSS, Javascript, and Jquery, so I'd need a patient response to help me solve this.

The page I'm working with is [my personal site](http://pavelrozman.com) and I'd like to apply this same type of keyboard navigation on all the pages on my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach a `keydown` event listener to the window, then see if it's an arrow key (keyCode 37 for Left, 38 for Up, 39 for Right and 40 for Down) and adjust `document.body.scrollTop` (and `document.documentElement.scrollTop` for some browsers) accordingly.

For instance:

```
var handler = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var k = e.keyCode || e.which;
    switch(k) {
      case 37:
        document.body.scrollLeft -= 1000;
        document.documentElement.scrollLeft -= 1000;
        break;
      case 38:
        document.body.scrollTop-= 1000;
        document.documentElement.scrollTop-= 1000;
        break;
      case 39:
        document.body.scrollLeft += 1000;
        document.documentElement.scrollLeft += 1000;
        break;
      case 40:
        document.body.scrollLeft += 1000;
        document.documentElement.scrollLeft += 1000;
        break;
      default: return true;
    }
    if( e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    return false;
};
if( window.attachEvent) window.addEvent("onkeydown",handler,false);
else window.addEventListener("keydown",handler,false);
```

You may also want to add `overflow:hidden` to prevent scrolling by other means (scrollbars, mouse wheel) to make sure the scrolling is in the proper increments.

Comment: Thank you so much for your super speedy response. Where exactly do I put this code? In an external script.js file or directly inline with the HTML and a <script> tag? I don't need overflow:hidden because I don't care how they scroll I just want all the options to be opened.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put the script.

Comment: Okay so far the script seems to work perfectly. It does exactly what I want. Thank you very much. The only problem is that now my smooth scroll JQuery script no longer works. If you click a link at the top of pavelrozman.com is will smoothly scroll you to the next place on the page. Can the arrow keys activate the smooth scrolling in the same way?

Comment: Hmm... I would imagine you could use jQuery's `$.scrollTo()` function, and pass `"+=1000"` or `"-=1000"` as the first argument and `{axis:x}` or `{axis:y}` as the second.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but the jQuery only works right before </head>. I put it there and it smoothly scrolls, but not when I use the arrows. This is okay though. I thank you immensely for your work.