# Enable arrow keys to navigate a vertical page

Tags: vertical-scrolling, arrow-keys

I have a website mainly consisting of vertical pages with photos. I want visitors to be able to use the arrow keys (up & down, left & right) on their keyboards to move upwards and downwards.

I tried [a code shared here at overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554552/how-to-use-arrow-keys-to-navigate-a-vertical-page/), but I can only make it work upwards with the up-arrow on my keyboard. When I press the other arrows nothing happens. I've tested in Chrome and Firefox in OS X on my MacBook Pro. [View my test-page](http://bjarteedvardsen.com/test.html).

Are there any code modifications I can do to make it work?

This is the code I tried:

```
var handler = function(e) {
e = e || window.event;
var k = e.keyCode || e.which;
switch(k) {
  case 37:
    document.body.scrollLeft -= 1000;
    document.documentElement.scrollLeft -= 1000;
    break;
  case 38:
    document.body.scrollTop-= 1000;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop-= 1000;
    break;
  case 39:
    document.body.scrollLeft += 1000;
    document.documentElement.scrollLeft += 1000;
    break;
  case 40:
    document.body.scrollLeft += 1000;
    document.documentElement.scrollLeft += 1000;
    break;
  default: return true;
  }
  if( e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
  return false;
};
if( window.attachEvent) window.addEvent("onkeydown",handler,false);
else window.addEventListener("keydown",handler,false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scroll left and right wont work if the page is not wider than the screen. You have assigned scrollLeft to the key 40 (down) so nothing will happen. The following code is corrected and works for up and down:

```
var handler = function(e) {
e = e || window.event;
var k = e.keyCode || e.which;
switch(k) {
  case 37:
    console.log("37 pressed");
    document.body.scrollLeft -= 1000;
    document.documentElement.scrollLeft -= 1000;
    break;
  case 38:
    console.log("38 pressed");
    document.body.scrollTop-= 1000;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop-= 1000;
    break;
  case 39:
    console.log("39 pressed");

    document.body.scrollLeft += 1000;
    document.documentElement.scrollLeft += 1000;
    break;
  case 40:
    console.log("40 pressed");
    document.body.scrollTop += 1000;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop += 1000;
    break;
  default: return true;
}
if( e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
return false;
}; 
if( window.attachEvent) window.addEvent("onkeydown",handler,false);
else window.addEventListener("keydown",handler,false);
```

Comment: Thanks alot, it works for up and down now. This sparks another question though. Is it possible that each time a visitor clicks up or down, no matter what position the visitor is at, that the click leads to the top of the next photo so that the visitor sees the whole photo? What kind of adjustments would I have to make then? Like here on this blog: http://www.theatlantic.com/infocus/2013/12/a-virtual-drive-around-iceland/100649/

Comment: Look into jQuery offset to calculate the position of the individual pictures and when a click event happens calculate the scroll position of the closest picture. Please try that on your own and ask a second question if you have specific problems.